# Как вывести превью определенного элемента на страницу битрикс?

Tags: php, битрикс

Возможно странный вопрос, но как вывести на обычную страницу не используя компоненты, анонс картинки элемента инфоблока в битрикс?

То есть есть инфоблок в котором есть элемент, у элемента есть картинка анонса, я хочу вывести ее в определенном месте на странице, но чет не пойму как это сделать, не используя компоненты.

Comment: Сделать запрос к инфоблоку. Помсотреть в каком виде возвращаются данные, найти где там картинка и вывести её.

Comment: А как это сделать, с компонентами я частично разобрался но не до конца еще. Хоть примерно. Или ссылочка на документацию есть где про это описано, а то я даже не знаю как вопрос сформулировать

Comment: https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/classes/ciblockelement/getlist.php

Comment: Благодарю, спасибо

Comment: "битрикс вывод картинки" это самое первое что надо было поискать.